# Docker Desktop fails to start

Tags: docker

I installed Docker Desktop (4.6) onto my work laptop (Windows 10 Enterprise, version 20H2, build 19042.1466). When I attempt to start it up I get the following error:

```
 See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
Docker.Core.BackendAPI.ServiceNotRunningException: Unable to start Docker Desktops service: 2
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.BackendAPIPipeResolver.<ResolvePipeAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.6.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\BackendAPIPipeResolver.cs:line 78
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.ServiceAPIClient.<CreateSystemHttpClientAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.6.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\ServiceAPIClient.cs:line 24
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.ServiceAPIClient.<TryGetVhdxSize>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.6.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\ServiceAPIClient.cs:line 135
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.SettingsAdjuster.<CopyVhdxSizeAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.6.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\SettingsAdjuster.cs:line 23
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.App.<InitializeAsync>d__25.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.6.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\App.cs:line 127
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.TaskExtension.<Forget>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.6.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Extensions.cs:line 50
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4420.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Docker Desktop
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.0.75818
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker%20Desktop.exe
----------------------------------------
Docker.Core
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.0.75818
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.Core.DLL
----------------------------------------
Docker.WPF
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.0.75818
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.WPF.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrowdStrike.Sensor.ScriptControl
    Assembly Version: 6.23.13702.0
    Win32 Version: 6.23.13702.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/System32/CrowdStrike.Sensor.ScriptControl13702.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/PresentationCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsBase
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xaml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xaml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll
----------------------------------------
Docker.ApiServices
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.0.75818
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.ApiServices.DLL
----------------------------------------
Docker.Engines
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.0.75818
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.Engines.DLL
----------------------------------------
Docker.HttpApi
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.0.75818
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.HttpApi.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4400.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
NLog
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.5.10.8381
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/NLog.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Newtonsoft.Json
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.2.21924
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Serialization
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Serialization/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
BITSReference5_0
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/BITSReference5_0.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream.NamedPipe
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.NamedPipe.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Net.Http
    Assembly Version: 4.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26011.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Net.Http.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
    Assembly Version: 4.2.0.1
    Win32 Version: 4.6.28619.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Http
    Assembly Version: 5.2.7.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.61128.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Web.Http.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream.Client
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.Client.DLL
----------------------------------------
netstandard
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/netstandard/v4.0_2.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51/netstandard.dll
----------------------------------------
Bugsnag
    Assembly Version: 2.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.2.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Bugsnag.DLL
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationTypes
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationTypes/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationTypes.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero2
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero2/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationProvider
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationProvider/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationProvider.dll
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4420.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications
    Assembly Version: 1.5.1.0
    Win32 Version: 1.5.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.25714.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Runtime.DLL
----------------------------------------
Windows.UI
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.UI.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Foundation
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Foundation.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
----------------------------------------
Windows.Data
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Data.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.ValueTuple
    Assembly Version: 4.0.3.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26515.06
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.ValueTuple.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Collections
    Assembly Version: 4.0.11.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.25714.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Collections.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
    Assembly Version: 4.0.4.1
    Win32 Version: 4.6.28619.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.DLL
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Owin
    Assembly Version: 4.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.81112.127
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Microsoft.Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
Owin
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream.Server.Owin
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.Server.Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
    Assembly Version: 4.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.81112.127
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Http.Owin
    Assembly Version: 5.2.7.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.61128.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Web.Http.Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Net.Http.Formatting
    Assembly Version: 5.2.7.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.61128.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL
----------------------------------------
SMDiagnostics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/SMDiagnostics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/SMDiagnostics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel.Internals
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel.Internals/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceProcess
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceProcess/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Resources.ResourceManager
    Assembly Version: 4.0.1.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.25714.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Resources.ResourceManager.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemXml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemXml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll
----------------------------------------
ReachFramework
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4110.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/ReachFramework/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/ReachFramework.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4261.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.SqlXml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.SqlXml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.SqlXml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.IdentityModel
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4455.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.IdentityModel/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IdentityModel.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Messaging
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Messaging/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Messaging.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.DurableInstancing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Services
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Web.Services/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics.Vectors
    Assembly Version: 4.1.4.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26515.06
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Numerics.Vectors.DLL
----------------------------------------
Windows.Graphics
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Graphics.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.System
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.System.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Devices
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Devices.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Gaming
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Gaming.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.ApplicationModel
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Storage
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Storage.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Web
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Web.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Media
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Media.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Security
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Security.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration.Install
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration.Install/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.Install.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I have WSL2 set up with Ubuntu. My end goal is to get Lando up and running but that's a whole different issue.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times. I have installed as admin, and run as admin. I have no idea how to get around this error.
When the error comes up I am given the option to either continue or quit. I can also see the details which is what I posted above. If I do choose to click continue then nothing happens. The icon for Docker Desktop is displayed in my tray, and when hovering over it it states "Docker Desktop is stopped". If I click on it then Docker Desktop opens, but just displays "Docker Desktop stopped..."